# Can I use the Amazon fire tablet to test my android react native apps?

Tags: android, react-native, testing

I'm looking for the cheapest simplest way to test my react-native apps on a physical device and am looking to buy an android device as my test mule.

The android fire tablet seems to be the cheapest one I can find - but I don't know if it has a bunch of custom Amazon adware that will make testing my custom apps on it difficult or problematic.

Should I be able to test my react-native app builds on Amazon fire just like any other android device - or will does it have customizations that will cause problems?

Do you have any other suggestions for a cheap, pain-free device to buy for android testing.

Comment: Yes you should be able to run your app. The amazon devices are only an issue if you use google libraries like play services. Just to be safe you can test the compatibility of your app with amazon devices on the following link: https://developer.amazon.com/app-testing-service

Comment: @Emanuel Canha, great answer, you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you should be able to run your app. The amazon devices are only an issue if you use google libraries like play services. Just to be safe you can test the compatibility of your app with amazon devices on the following link: https://developer.amazon.com/app-testing-service

Comment: So does that mean that services like GCM cannot be used on the fire tablet?

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey yes that is correct and I have confirmed that with an Amazon evangelist